# Calling a dll from Mathematica

Tags: .netlink

I would like to call the following function from Mathematica

```
ps3000aOpenUnit
PICO_STATUS ps3000aOpenUnit
(
   short * handle,
   char * serial
)
```

I define the DLLFunciton in Mathematica:

```
ps3000OpenUnit =  DefineDLLFunction["ps3000aOpenUnit", "PS3000a.dll", "short", {"short[]", "char[]"}]
```

I get following error when executing

```
ps3000OpenUnit[handle, serial]
NET::methodargs: Improper arguments supplied for method named ps3000aOpenUnit.
```

What is wrong with my code?

Thanx for helping me in advance.

Comment: I don't recall "short" or "char" being a valid type for the definition - shouldn't they be "integer" and "string" (or "char*"?

Comment: It seems like your function signature declares your parameters as pointers, but in your `DefineDLLFunction` you specify arrays. What are the values of `handle` and `serial`?

Answer (score 2):

"short" or "char" are in the C programming language data typs.

Try this:

```
ps3000aOpenUnit = 
  DefineDLLFunction["ps3000aOpenUnit", "ps3000a.dll", "short", {"short*"}];

handle=0;
status = ps3000aOpenUnit[handle];
```

Comment: I tried this. However I am getting an error.

    NET::netexcptn: A .NET exception occurred: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at Wolfram.NETLink.DynamicDLLNamespace.DLLWrapper1.ps3000aOpenUnit(Int16& ).


any suggestions? Tnx!